# Repeatable custom meta select boxes

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, select

I am working on meta fields for a custom post type storing match data. 
I have two sepearte meta boxes one which the team and the score are chosen and the values are submitted.

The second takes that information and provides a series of select boxes in which players from the team in question are displayed. As there are several goals scored, several players are chosen (some more than once)

I am working off a tutorial http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-3-extra-fields/ and am modifying the code to use repeat select boxes. This is what I have come up with:

```
$goal_info_meta_fields = array(
    'label' => 'Home Goals by:',
    'desc' => 'List home scorers',
    'id' => $prefix.'home-scorers',
    'type' => 'home_player_list'
);

function show_goal_info_meta_box() {
global $goal_info_meta_fields, $post;


echo '<input type="hidden" name="goal_info_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';


echo '<table class="admin-table">';
foreach ($goal_info_meta_fields as $field) {

    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

    echo '<tr>
        <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
        <td>';
    switch($field['type']) {

        // home_player_list
    case 'home_player_list':
        echo '<a class="repeatable-add button" href="#">+</a>
            <ul id="'.$field['id'].'-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable">';
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $team_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'report_home-select');

        $items = get_users( array (
                'meta_key' => 'team-meta',
                'meta_value' => $team_id
            ));
        $i = 0;
        if ($meta) {
            foreach($meta as $row) {
                echo '<li><span class="sort hndle button">|||</span>';
                echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.']" class="chzn-select" style="width:200px;" id="report_home-scorers">
                <option value="">Select One</option>'; // Select One
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$meta == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>'.$item->display_name.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select><a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>';

                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            echo '<li><span class="sort hndle button">|||</span>';
            echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.']" class="chzn-select" style="width:200px;" id="'.$field['id'].'">
            <option value="">Select One</option>'; // Select One

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$meta == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>'.$item->display_name.'</option>';
            }

            echo '</select><a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>';

        }
        echo '</ul><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
        break;


    } //end switch
    echo '</td></tr>';
} // end foreach
echo '</table>'; // end table
```

}

It works perfectly if I use text imputs but not the select boxes and I think the problem is that `$meta == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' :` and currently `$meta = a:1:{i:0;s:3:"179";}` I've tried unserializing the array as well.

The tutorial I've used has a github repository https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes which I tried as well but I couldn't apply the repeatable example as the options are in a loop I can't use a foreach statement in an array.

I would love some help with this as I've been tearing my hair out for the past two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work...

```
$meta == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
```

... with an array like `a:1:{i:0;s:3:"179";}` which unserializes to...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 179
)
```

... you'd need to do this:

```
$meta =  unserialize($meta);
$meta[0] == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
```

But that line shows up inside a `foreach` like `foreach($meta as $row) {`, at least in one place, so I am wondering why it isn't written...

```
$row == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
```

And the second time that line-- `$meta[0] == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : ''` -- shows up is inside an `else` that should not execute unless `$meta` is empty, so it shouldn't using the variable at all.

I'd suggest that you [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and take a good look around.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response though I'm not entirely sure I understood it correctly. So in the first one where $meta has data I do `$row == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : and the second isn't needed anyway? I do have debugging enabled but I only get errors before I submit the team name data.

Comment: I think so, yes. It looks to me like `$row` should be your ID and inside that `else` `$meta` isn't populated so there is no point in checking it.

Comment: still returning a single value inside an array. I've tried `foreach($meta[$i] as $row) {,` but still no luck.

Comment: Got it! You were dead on with `$row == $item->ID ?  selected="selected"' : ` I made a mistake cloning the box and cloned the `[0]`as well. Thank you again! I would give you a +1 but my rep isn't good enough.